# compare two csv files and fetch matching data

Tags: shell, text-processing, csv

I have two .csv files namely file1.csv and file2.csv

**file1.csv**

```
ADIS
BAP3
Mercury_System
nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT
```

**file2.csv**

```
ADIS,projects.adis
EcoSystems,projects.ecosystems
em1xxxsw,projects.em1xxxsw
BAP3,projects.bap3
Dirana4,projects.dirana4
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DocStore,projects.docstore
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

**Desired output.csv**

```
ADIS,projects.adis
BAP3,projects.bap3
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

I have already tried couple of codes below, but none of them worked for me as per the requirement

```
grep -Ff file1.csv file2.csv > outfile.csv

awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next} ($1 in seen)' file1.csv file2.csv > outfile.csv
```

file1.csv contains 2500 rows and file2.csv contains 118 rows, so it should compare and give me only results which are matching to file2, output should be matching to 118 rows/results.

Comment: its not a duplicate of the question mentioned as this is a csv file that i have asked and the one you mentioned is piped file.

Comment: Even that didn't have a solution

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between the contents of a file and piped contents, as long as they are both finite.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When I do `grep -Ff file1 file2` I get your desired output (using `grep` in macOS).

Comment: @maulinglawns i have tried it, but i am on RHEL. It's not working here, even with awk i get a blank output

Comment: @here can anyone please help me out

Comment: @I0b0 even i tried with the duplicate you mentioned but didn't help

Comment: Tested `grep -Ff file1.csv file2.csv` on CentOS 6.2 with GNU grep 2.20 and it works for me. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @SiddharthSahoo it would help to know what exactly is going wrong.. in one of the comments you mentioned `awk` is giving blank output..  are you getting blank output with `grep` too? can you post what is the output of `seq 3 6 > f1 ; seq 5 > f2 ; grep -Ff f1 f2` ?

Comment: You wrote that file1.csv has 2500 rows and file2.csv has 118 rows. Maybe you want to reverse the order of file, and compare according to the 118 rows.

Comment: @Sundeep yes both give empty result, i don't see any content in the output file

Comment: @andreatsh i tried that too but didnt work out

Comment: Can anyone please provide an answer ??

Comment: For clarification: I voted to close this question because it *can't be reproduced*: both the awk and the grep commands print the desired output. There's something else going on with the OP's situation. It could be mis-matched character encodings or DOS line endings; I'd suggest [edit]ing the question to include the results of `file file1.csv file2.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

The following grep should return the desired results assuming file1.csv has only one column for each row.  This uses each line in file1.csv as a search string (needle) and searches through file2.csv (haystack).

```
grep -f file1.csv file2.csv | tee outfile.csv
```

I added `tee` so you can see the output as well as writing it to a file.  Your question is very vague as to what problem you are experiencing.  I've done this many times on RHEL and Debian and tested just now with your sample contents.  I was able to achieve your desired results.

Comment: i have already tried this option but no use, now i tried on GNU/Linux but still nothing i get